# Is it a good design to use REST, HTTPS and JSON for sending large data?

Tags: json, rest, hbase

We are up to build API which deals with HBase table. Let's say the API has to methods: `api.com/get/`to get something out of HBase  and `api.com/put/` to put a matrix into HBase. We want to put and get matrices of size 200mb.

We can't come to conclusion of how to send data to this API. Do you think it sounds OK to send HTTPS request and represent the 200mb input matrix as JSON and put it to POST parameter?

Can't find any best practices for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The payload limits depends of the client and server RAM size and processor.

Teorically there is no limit in the standard (RFC 2616). However is not a good idea to construct a big payload because it probably fails because of one of this reasons:

1. lost packets on data transmission
2. limits on server side
3. limits on client side

The best is try to split your 200mb input matrix in smaller inputs and make multiple requests.